# Phonegap Build in iphone exec error

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I've got a strange one here i'm trying to use [PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS/blob/46f3af92ed6c98265cab8bccafef906271b3e554/README.md) to add in app purchasing to my phonegap application. However, on load on the iphone the device always says `'TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.exec')` and I THINK it's stopping my init running.

When I try and do a purchase i'm getting the error `' InAppPurchase[js]: purchase error: product needs to be loaded before purchase, call storekit.load(...) first!'` but heres my index.js - you can see from this I am running the storekit.load first. I don't know if the two issues are linked and that's stopping the rest of the JS running? From what I can see, i'm not running cordova.exec?

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        console.log("Attempting to init");
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        try {
            FB.init({appId: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsd", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false});
            console.log("FB Ready");
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }

        inappbilling.init(bSuccess, bError, {showLog:true}, "asdass");

    },
    bindEvents: function() {


    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {

        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        window.storekit.init({

            debug: true, /* Because we like to see logs on the console */

            purchase: function (transactionId, productId) {
                console.log('purchased: ' + productId);
            },
            restore: function (transactionId, productId) {
                console.log('restored: ' + productId);
            },
            restoreCompleted: function () {
                console.log('all restore complete');
            },
            restoreFailed: function (errCode) {
                console.log('restore failed: ' + errCode);
            },
            error: function (errno, errtext) {
                console.log('Failed: ' + errtext);
            },
            ready: function () {
                var productIds = [
                    "com.asdad.asdads.asdasd"
                ];
                window.storekit.load(productIds, function(validProducts, invalidProductIds) {
                    $.each(validProducts, function (i, val) {
                        console.log("id: " + val.id + " title: " + val.title + " val: " + val.description + " price: " + val.price);
                    });
                    if(invalidProductIds.length) {
                        console.log("Invalid Product IDs: " + JSON.stringify(invalidProductIds));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    },
    tokenHandler:function(msg) {
        localStorage.setItem("Device", "ios");
        console.log("Token Handler " + msg);
        localStorage.setItem("PushID", msg)

    },
    errorHandler:function(error) {
        console.log("Error Handler  " + error);
        alert(error);
    },
    // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    successHandler: function(result) {

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            pushNotification.register(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler,{"senderID":"asdasdadsasd","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
        }
        else {

            pushNotification.register(this.tokenHandler,this.errorHandler,{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.onNotificationAPN"});
        }
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    // iOS
    onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        console.log("Received a notification! " + event.alert);
        console.log("event sound " + event.sound);
        console.log("event badge " + event.badge);
        console.log("event " + event);
        if (event.alert) {
            navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);

        }

        if (event.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(event.sound);
            snd.play();
        }
    },
    // Android
    onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                  localStorage.setItem("PushID", e.regid)

                }
                break;

            case 'message':
                // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model
                // of the intermediary push server which must also be reflected in GCMIntentService.java
                alert(e.message);
                break;

            case 'error':
                alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
                break;

            default:
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                break;
        }
    }

};
function bSuccess(result) {
    alert("woo - initialised");
}

function bError(error) {
    alert(error);
}

function updateID() {
    console.log("Updating ID on server");

    var Username = localStorage.getItem("Username");
    var SessionKey = localStorage.getItem("SessionID");
    var PushID =  localStorage.getItem("PushID");
    alert(PushID);
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "b", text: "Loading", textonly: false});
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://taasdasdasdasdgi.asdasdasdasdasd.com/Register.asmx/RegisterDevice",
        data: {  Username: Username, SessionKey: SessionKey, PushId:PushID, UUid:"moo", ProductType: localStorage.getItem("Device") },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: onDataReceived
    });

    function onDataReceived(data)
    {

        $.mobile.loading( 'hide', { theme: "b", text: "", textonly: false});

    }
}
function successHandler1 (result) {
    console.log(result);
    var strResult = "";
    if(typeof result === 'object') {
        strResult = JSON.stringify(result);
    } else {
        strResult = result;
    }

}
function errorHandler1 (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
}
function subscribe(){
    // make the purchase
    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
        inappbilling.buy(successHandler1, errorHandler1,"asdasdsa");
    }
    else {
        window.storekit.purchase("com.asdsaddas.asdasd.asdasdasd", 1);
    }
    console.log("Trying to buy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem. I have solved this problem with the following steps.                                                                                                                        (1). Bind "device ready" event to your app. This code should be written in main index.js file.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady , false);
```

(2). Then put the code of "onDeviceReady" function in the index.js file. 
For example:

```
    function onDeviceReady(){ 
        window.storekit.init({

        debug: true, /* Because we like to see logs on the console */

        purchase: function (transactionId, productId) {
            console.log('purchased: ' + productId);
        },
        restore: function (transactionId, productId) {
            console.log('restored: ' + productId);
        },
        restoreCompleted: function () {
            console.log('all restore complete');
        },
        restoreFailed: function (errCode) {
            console.log('restore failed: ' + errCode);
        },
        error: function (errno, errtext) {
            console.log('Failed: ' + errtext);
        },
        ready: function () {
            var productIds = [
                "com.asdad.asdads.asdasd"
            ];
            window.storekit.load(productIds, function(validProducts, invalidProductIds) {
                $.each(validProducts, function (i, val) {
                    console.log("id: " + val.id + " title: " + val.title + " val: " + val.description + " price: " + val.price);
                });
                if(invalidProductIds.length) {
                    console.log("Invalid Product IDs: " + JSON.stringify(invalidProductIds));
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
}
```

This is working for me.